# Force flutter_google_places to only display cities when using GooglePlacesAutocompleteWidget

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using the flutter_google_places widget to search for cities.

I've tried the AutoComplete example given with the widget and it works perfectly. But when I type "Paris" for example, I get many results of places in Paris (Paris, Paris Airport, Paris Expo, etc.).

I only need cities within my App. So for example, when typing "Paris", I would only want "Paris (France), Paris (Texas), Paris (Tennessee), etc.

I haven't found how to apply the "cities" filter.

Here is the equivalent in Javascript :

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchField');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this example: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Should do

```
  CustomSearchScaffold()
      : super(
          apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
          sessionToken: Uuid().generateV4(),
          language: "en",
          components: [Component(Component.country, "uk")],
          types: ["(cities)"], // or cities
        );
```

Comment: Thank you. ["cities"] doesn't work but ["(cities)"] does. I found a reference here : https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/example/10-places/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch/page.dart

Comment: I have no idea why () are required nor where to find the information for the different types available.